# ${} template literal (ES2015) conflict with JSP EL syntax

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, ecmascript-6, el

${} is being used by both JSP and JS, so what's happening is that the ${} in the JS template literals are being interpreted and remove before being compiled into servlets. Is there a way I can tell Java to ignore ${} without completely turning the feature off with isELIgnored?

```
const subject = 'world';
let greet = `hello ${subject}!`
```

turns into the following in the browser

```
const subject = 'world';
let greet = `hello !`
```

Here's the best I've come up with, really not digging how ugly it is though.

```
<c:out value="var body = `pq_country=${country}&pq_population=${population}`;" escapeXml='false'/>
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you using back-ticks?

Comment: ES6 only substitutes these values when you use backticks as the delimiter. Have you tried using simple apostrophes?

Comment: Just write JS code in its own JS file instead of mixing with HTML source. That has been the "best practice" for ages.

Comment: It is different to write JS in its own file for "best practice" and different for writing because you don't have any choice. Too bad that this conflict cannot be solved in a better way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to move the JS code to the function inside the external file or `script` tag, it would be the best way to solve conflict of jsp with JS syntax.

Answer (score 17):

You can put a backslash in front of the ${} so JSP ignores it (found out through [this article](https://medium.com/@daveford/template-literals-not-working-f5f0c7553f8b) by David Ford).

```
const subject = 'world';
let greet = `hello \${subject}!`
```