# ${} template literal (ES2015) is work under jsp pages

Tags: javascript, jsp, ecmascript-5

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
 <title>Document</title>
 
</head>
<body>
 <h2> why ${variableName} is in consider as undefined in jsp page
 <script>
  let x="x";
  console.log(`${x} is the variable`)

 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**${}** is consider as undefined in jsp pages.
Please tell me how it is coming as not expexted.
Thank You!

Comment: You should always look at the generated HTML, it would have been obvious.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [${} template literal (ES2015) conflict with JSP EL syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39229285/template-literal-es2015-conflict-with-jsp-el-syntax)

Answer (score 0):

**The fix is to escape the ${myVar} with a backslash so that JSP ignores it:**

```
//my.jsp
<script>
   var n = "Dave";
   var s = `Hello \${n}`;  //note the backslash
</script>
```